# Dynamic search and turn a word into bold with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Good Evening everyone. I'm new to JavaScript and I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. I've created an `<input type="text"/>` through which I want to specify which words to make **bold**.

Currently I have the following code:

```js
<script>
   someFunctionRun() {
     var str = document.getElementById("oldnew").innerHTLM;
     var search = document.getElementById("search");
     var regex = new RegExp(search, 'g');
     var result = str.replace(regex, '<b>'+search+'</b>');
     document.getElementById("old-new").innerHTML = result.value;
   }
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" value="" onkeyup="someFunctionRun()">
<div id="old-new">My sentence goes here</div>
```

One requirement is, that I need to get a solution in pure JavaScript.

Comment: Inside `<script>` function syntax should be like this `var someFunctionRun = function() { // statement; };` or `function someFunctionRun() { //statement; }`

Comment: `innerHTLM` should be `innerHTML`.

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes in your code: extraneous script tags, misspelled property names, passing a DOM element instead of its text into RegExp constructor...

Comment: @brk it creates a regular expression

Comment: 1) install a linter! 2) visit your console. they tell you whats wrong with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your work, might be helpful.

```js
var str = document.getElementById("old-new").innerHTML; // this is for keeping the old content as is

var someFunctionRun = function() {
  var search = document.getElementById("search").value; // for finding inputs value use ".value"
  var regex = new RegExp(search, 'g');
  var result = str.replace(regex, '<b>' + search + '</b>');
  document.getElementById("old-new").innerHTML = result;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" value="" onkeyup="someFunctionRun()">
<div id="old-new">My sentence goes here as here goes my sentence</div>
```

Comment: I learned something from everyone's answers but this solution worked better for me since it is the most similar to my code, thank you to everybody

Comment: This will error if you type symbols such as `(` or `[`

Answer (score 1):

Andy's comment below is correct, apologies.

One difference here from what you have above is this creates a group matching the input with case insensitivity. This way, if you type "hello" vs "Hello" it will still match, and you can easily target the matched string with the `$1` placeholder.

We need to "cache" the content of the div to match against (line 3), and then update the innerHTML after we match.

```js
    const input = document.getElementById('input')
    const div = document.getElementById('target') 
    const divText = div.innerHTML;

    input.addEventListener('input', onInput);

    function onInput(e) {
      let regex = new RegExp('(' + input.value + ')', 'i');
      let newStr = divText.replace(regex, '<b>$1</b>');
      div.innerHTML = newStr;
    }
```

```html
<div id="target">Hello, I am some text.</div>
<input id="input">
```

Comment: It's useful to add notes to explain what you've changed, and what the OP might have done better, rather than just drop a load of code.

Answer (score 1):

1) It's best to separate out your JS from your HTML. Instead of inline code, pick up an element and give it an event listener.

2) You misspelled `innerHTML` and `old-new` in your example.

3) You only have to pick up elements once. They can be cached in a variable.

4) Instead of `var search = document.getElementById("search")` you needed to pick up the input's `value`. And since we cached the input element all you need is `var search = input.value`.

```js
var output = document.getElementById("old-new");
var str = output.innerHTML;

var input = document.getElementById("search");
input.addEventListener('keyup', someFunctionRun, false);

function someFunctionRun(e) {
  var search = input.value;
  var regex = new RegExp(search, 'g');
  var result = str.replace(regex, '<b>' + search + '</b>');
  output.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" value="">
<div id="old-new">My sentence goes here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally work in "pure javascript" (I use jQuery), but I see several things that look like errors...

Here are some fixes...

```
function someFunctionRun() {
    var str = document.getElementById("old-new").innerHTML;
    var search = document.getElementById("search");
    var regex = new RegExp(search, 'g');
    var result = str.replace(regex, '<b>'+search+'</b>');
    document.getElementById("old-new").innerHTML = result.value;

}
```

The fixes:

- Add the keyword`function` before your function name
- Use the correct element Id (first line inside function)
- Spell "HTML" correctly (first line inside function)

Comment: Someone edited my reply as I was editing -- lost my additional text :(

Comment: You can back-out the edits if someone screwed with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="search" value="" onkeyup="someFunctionRun()">
    <div id="old-new">My sentence goes here</div>
  </body>
  <script>
    var str = document.getElementById("old-new").innerHTML;

    function someFunctionRun() {
    var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
    result = str.replace(search, search.bold());
    document.getElementById("old-new").innerHTML = result;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Avoid typos, there were a lot of them...

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your code:

- You did not declare a function properly. Use either `var someFunctionRun = function() {...}` or `function someFunctionRun() {...}`
- You are passing a DOM node, assigned to `search`, into the `new RegExp` constructor. This throws an error because it is not a string. Use `.value` to access the value of the input element instead
- When setting the innerHTML of your target element, you do not need to access the `value` node of `result`, since it is already a string
- You have a typo in selecting the ID: it should be `old-new` not `oldNew`

This will give you a function, with no syntax error but **still does not work** (we will get into that immediately):

```
function someFunctionRun() {
  var str = document.getElementById("old-new").innerHTML;
  var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
  var regex = new RegExp(search, 'g');
  var result = str.replace(regex, '<b>' + search + '</b>');
  document.getElementById("old-new").innerHTML = result;
}
```

The reason? You are constantly updating the markup of your target element, which means the regex quickly fails. Imagine this:

1. You type `s`
2. This matches the `s` in `sentence`
3. This replaces the inner HTML with `<b>s</b>entrance`
4. You then type `se`
5. This will no longer match your updated markup

So what you need is actually to store the inner HTML/text somewhere—we can use the HTML5 dataset API for that:

```js
function someFunctionRun() {
  var sentence = document.getElementById("old-new")
  var str = sentence.innerHTML;
  
  // Store its original markup somewhere
  if (!sentence.dataset.originalText) {
    sentence.dataset.originalText = str;
  } else {
    str = sentence.dataset.originalText; 
  }
  
  var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
  var regex = new RegExp(search, 'g');
  var result = str.replace(regex, '<b>' + search + '</b>');
  sentence.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" value="" onkeyup="someFunctionRun()">
<div id="old-new">My sentence goes here</div>
```